# opencv build errors in eclipse on linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, opencv

Hie guys. I am trying to compile C++ code using the opencv library but I am facing challenges. All image processing i.e imread,imshow and all they are working fine but when I try to load a video file using VideoCapture my c++ code is not building in eclipse luna in the linux environment. I have added a small code snippet just to test video support using VideoCapture but it is not working. Can someone help me solve this problem.This is the output from the eclipse console and the small c++ code snippet.

```c++
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    VideoCapture capture("traffic.mp4");
}
```

```
20:14:05 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project RealTimeObjectTracking ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: RealTimeObjectTracking
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "RealTimeObjectTracking"  ./main.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d  -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavcodec.so.54, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
makefile:44: recipe for target 'RealTimeObjectTracking' failed
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavformat.so.54, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavutil.so.52, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libswscale.so.2, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_getContext@LIBSWSCALE_2'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_sub_q@LIBAVUTIL_52'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_opt_set@LIBAVUTIL_52'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_alloc_context@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_free@LIBAVUTIL_52'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avio_close@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_seek_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_codec_get_id@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_frame@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_read_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_free_context@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_getCachedContext@LIBSWSCALE_2'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_write_header@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_guess_format@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_video@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_register_all@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_write_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_free_packet@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_new_stream@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_rescale_q@LIBAVUTIL_52'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avpicture_get_size@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_encoder@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_freep@LIBAVUTIL_52'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_context_defaults3@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avio_open@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avpicture_fill@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_lockmgr_register@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_init_packet@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_open_input@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_scale@LIBSWSCALE_2'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_network_init@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_flush_buffers@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_find_stream_info@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_close_input@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_decode_video2@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_write_trailer@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_log_set_level@LIBAVUTIL_52'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_freeContext@LIBSWSCALE_2'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_open2@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_malloc@LIBAVUTIL_52'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_close@LIBAVCODEC_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_guess_codec@LIBAVFORMAT_54'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RealTimeObjectTracking] Error 1
```

Comment: There is an error that the linker cannot find /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so . Did you check to see if it is there?

Comment: you need libavformat libavutil and libswscale
in ubuntu you can get them: sudo apt-get install libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev